# Why is xpath not selecting elements with empty classes on using `not`?

Tags: html, xpath

Here's a minimum reproducible scenario.

```html
<tr> Hello </tr>
<tr class="heisenberg"> I'm the one who knocks. </tr>
<tr class="lennon"> Imagine no errors. </tr>
```

And I want all the `<tr>` except the one with class `"heisenberg"`. I did this:

```xml
tr[@class!="heisenberg"]
```

This xpath is selecting `lennon` but **not** the one with **empty class**. Why ? What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath assumes that node *has `class` attribute and it is not equal to `"heisenberg"`*

Try this one to select node that *doesn't contain specific `@class`*

```
tr[not(@class="heisenberg")]
```

If node can contain multiple class names you can also try

```
tr[not(contains(@class, "heisenberg"))]
```

Comment: To expand on this answer: all the comparison operators (`=`, `!=`, `<`, etc) in XPath have *existential* semantics: `A ~ B` means "there is an a in A and a b in B such that a ~ b". So `@class != 'heisenberg'` means "In the node-set selected by `@class` there is a node whose value is not equal to "heisenberg" -- which is not true if the node-set selected by `@class` is empty. This is why `not(X=Y)` is more likely to achieve the result you want than `X != Y`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:
tr[not(@class) or @class!="heisenberg"]